# Protecting a specific Pat route

Tags: go, routes

The only way I have figured out how to protect a specific route, e.g. `/secret` but have `/` using [pat](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/pat) is something like:

```
app := pat.New()
app.Get("/", hello) // The should be public

shh := pat.New()
shh.Get("/secret", secret) // I want to protect this one only

http.Handle("/secret", protect(shh))
http.Handle("/", app)
```

I find it strange that I have two pat.Routers and I must be careful to map the routes. [Full working example.](https://play.golang.org/p/5F-hII2oAo5)

Am I missing a trick to do something simpler like `app.Get("/", protect(http.HandlerFunc(secret)))`? But this doesn't work since I am unable to `(type http.Handler) as type http.HandlerFunc in argument to app.Get: need type assertion` as [what I tried](https://play.golang.org/p/Wrfq4OHcgXr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `secret` to an [http.HandlerFunc](https://godoc.org/net/http#HandlerFunc) so it can be used as the `http.Handler` expected by `protect`.  Use [Router.Add](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/pat#Router.Add) which accepts the type returned by `protect`.

```
app := pat.New()
app.Get("/", hello) /
app.Add("GET", "/secret", protect(http.HandlerFunc(secret)))
http.Handle("/", app)
```

An another approach is to change `protect` to accept and return `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`:

```
func protect(h func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()
        match := user == "tobi" && pass == "ferret"
        if !ok || !match {
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Ferret Land"`)
            http.Error(w, "Not authorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        h(w, r)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
app := pat.New()
app.Get("/", hello) 
app.Get("/secret", protect(secret))
http.Handle("/", app)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to convert the original protect's http.Handler to the (r, w) type it expects?

Comment: Convert like this: `func torw(h http.Handler) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) { return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { h.ServeHTTP(w, r) }}`. If you don't want to modify `protect`, then use `Route.Add` as suggested in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Actually in you code sample I am hitting `./main.go:30:28: cannot use secret (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in argument to protect:
        func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)` http://play.golang.org/p/ZFDy18LmM7u

Comment: Could be slightly better formatted to remove trailing slash on the hello line